# Decorator Design Pattern without concrete objects

Tags: design-patterns, decorator

I see Decorator DP examples, but all of them imply, that concrete object will be at the end of chain:

```cs
IProduct prod2 = new Sugar(new Sugar(new Sugar(new Milk(new DarkRoast()))));
Console.WriteLine("I am {0}, my cost is {1}", prod2.Name(), prod2.Cost());
```

DarkRoast is a concrete object, other object - is a decorators. So, I (or client) need to remember who is at the and of creation chain.

So, by default, I can not do:

```cs
IProduct prod2 = new Sugar(new DarkRoast(new Sugar(new Milk(new Sugar()))));
Console.WriteLine("I am {0}, my cost is {1}", prod2.Name(), prod2.Cost());
```

But, the meaning (I think) is same: Dark roast cofee + 3 sugar + 1 milk.

So, I redesign it to:

```cs
public interface IProduct {
    double Cost();
    string Name();
}

public class DarkRoast : IProduct {
    IProduct _product;

    public DarkRoast(IProduct prod = null) { _product = prod; }

    public double Cost() {
        if (_product != null) { return 2.5 + _product.Cost(); }
        else { return 2.5; }
    }

    public string Name() {
        if (_product != null) { return "DarkRoast " + _product.Name(); }
        else { return "DarkRoast "; }
    }
}

public class Milk : IProduct {
    IProduct _product;

    public Milk(IProduct prod = null) { _product = prod; }

    public double Cost() {
        if (_product != null) { return 0.5 + _product.Cost(); }
        else { return 0.5; }
    }

    public string Name() {
        if (_product != null) { return "With milk " + _product.Name(); }
        else { return "With milk "; }
    }
}

public class Sugar : IProduct {
    IProduct _product;

    public Sugar(IProduct prod = null) { _product = prod; }

    public double Cost() {
        if (_product != null) { return 0.2 + _product.Cost(); }
        else { return 0.2; }
    }

    public string Name() {
        if (_product != null) { return "With sugar " + _product.Name(); }
        else { return "With sugar "; }
    }
}
```

It is make me possible do

```cs
IProduct prod2 = new Sugar(new DarkRoast(new Sugar(new Milk(new Sugar()))));
Console.WriteLine("I am {0}, my cost is {1}", prod2.Name(), prod2.Cost());
```

So, I do not need to remember order of stuff. 
And, I think all stuff here is decorators (is it a bad idea?)
What are disadvantages of these implementation?

Comment: Well. It depends on the usage. The last console writeline suggests shopping? In that case it's not a good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks reasonable to me, but it might be slightly improved by adding a concrete [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) used as the default delegate object and thus avoiding the null checks.

Modulo my knowledge of your language syntax (it's a language I don't actually use), this would look something like this:

```
public class Empty : IProduct
{

    public double Cost()
    {
        return 0.0;
    }

    public string Name()
    {
        return "";
    }
}


public class Sugar : IProduct
{
    IProduct _product;


    public Sugar(IProduct prod = null) 
    {  
        _product = (prod == null) ? new Empty() : prod;
    }

    public double Cost()
    {
        return 0.2 + _product.Cost();
    }

    public string Name()
    {
        return "With sugar " + _product.Name();
    }
}
```

Comment: A little fix: you can not do :
IProduct prod = new Empty()

You need to do:
public DarkRoast(IProduct prod = null)
        {
            _product = (prod == null) ? new Empty() : prod;
        }

Comment: @zzfima Thanks, I thought that might be needed, but not really knowing the language, didn't do it.  I'll change it now.

Comment: I think it's perfectly reasonable.